# inorder traversal of a b-tree (c++)

Tags: c++, traversal, b-tree

I'm working on a b-tree (or is it BTree?) for a class I'm current taking. I have most of it implement correctly (I think). However, I'm having trouble nailing down an inorder traversal. Here's my main function:

```
Tree<char, 5>* tree = new Tree<char, 5>();

char entries[] = {'a', 'g', 'f', 'b', 'k', 'd', 'h', 'm', 'j', 'e', 's', 
                  'i', 'r', 'x', 'c', 'l', 'n', 't', 'u', 'p' };

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    tree->insert(entries[i]);
    cout << i << ":\t";
    tree->inorder();
    cout << endl;
}
```

So I'm create a 5-way btree that holds chars. I'm inserting each of the chars into the tree, and then showing the inorder traversal for each iteration for debugging purposes. This is the output I get:

```
0:  a
1:  ag
2:  afg
3:  abfg
4:  abffgk
5:  abdgfgk
6:  abdgfghk
7:  abdgfghkm
8:  abdgfghjjkm
9:  abdefghjjkm
10: abdefghjjkms
11: abdefghimjkms
12: abdefghimjkmrs
13: abdefghimjkmrrsx
14: abccdefghimjkmrrsx
15: abccdefghimjklmsrsx
16: abccdefghimjklmnrsx
17: abccdefghimjklmnrstx
18: abccdefghimjklmnrstux
19: abccdefghimjjklmmnprstux
```

In nearly all of them, some of the chars are duplicated, but not consistently between insertions, so it (to me) doesn't seem like duplicate data is getting in. I can't seem to make sense of it, but here's my inorder method:

```
template <class Record, int order>
void Tree<Record, order>::inorder()
{
    inorder(root);
}

template <class Record, int order>
void Tree<Record, order>::inorder(Node<Record, order> *current)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < current->count+1; i++) {
        if (current->branch[i])
            inorder(current->branch[i]);
        if (i < order-1 && current->data[i])
            cout << current->data[i];
    }
}
```

In my node implementation, count is the number of 'data' (each char) in the tree. count+1 would be how many branches come off the node for the non-leaf nodes. branch is an array of the next lower set of nodes, data is an array of the chars.

Here's my Node implementation:

```
template <class Record, int order>
struct Node
{
    int count;
    Record data[order - 1];
    Node<Record, order>* branch[order];
    Node() : count(0) {}
};
```

Here's everything used to insert:

```
template <class Record, int order>
ErrorCode Tree<Record, order>::insert(const Record& new_entry)
{
    Record median;
    Node<Record, order> *right_branch, *new_root;
    ErrorCode result = push_down(root, new_entry, median, right_branch);

    if (result == overflow) {
        new_root = new Node<Record, order>();
        new_root->count = 1;
        new_root->data[0] = median;
        new_root->branch[0] = root;
        new_root->branch[1] = right_branch;
        root = new_root;
        result = success;
    }

    return result;
}

template <class Record, int order>
ErrorCode Tree<Record, order>::push_down(
                Node<Record, order> *current,
                const Record &new_entry,
                Record &median,
                Node<Record, order> *&right_branch)
{
    ErrorCode result;
    int position;

    if (current == NULL) {
        median = new_entry;
        right_branch = NULL;
        result = overflow;
    }
    else {
        if (search_node(current, new_entry, position) == success)
            result = duplicate_error;
        else {
            Record extra_entry;
            Node<Record, order> *extra_branch;
            result = push_down(current->branch[position], new_entry, 
                                extra_entry, extra_branch);
            if (result == overflow) {
                if (current->count < order - 1) {
                    result = success;
                    push_in(current, extra_entry, extra_branch, position);
                }
                else
                    split_node(current, extra_entry, extra_branch, position, 
                                right_branch, median);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

template <class Record, int order>
void Tree<Record, order>::push_in(Node<Record, order> *current, 
                const Record &entry,
                Node<Record, order> *right_branch,
                int position)
{
    for (int i = current->count; i > position; i--) {
        current->data[i] = current->data[i-1];
        current->branch[i+1] = current->branch[i];
    }

    current->data[position] = entry;
    current->branch[position+1] = right_branch;
    current->count++;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the Node data structure - I don't understand why `branch` is apparently `count + 1` elements long. Showing the structure is clearer than trying to describe it. Also, what does the 'order' template parameter control?

Comment: the order template parameter controls what order of a tree we're working with. In this case, a 5-way tree (Tree<char, 5>* tree = new Tree<char, 5>). Adding node now ....

Comment: @greggory.hz can you clarify what 'count' means?  Is it the number of branches which have been added? or the number of 'data' elements? or something else?  I think there might be a bug with how count is used but its hard to tell without knowing how 'insert' uses it.

Comment: @greggory.hz can you provide the code for insert (if its not too big) I think the second bug something to do with 'count' and your for-loop

Comment: It's kind of a lot, but I've added the insert code

Comment: @greggory.hz its really hard to tell, i'm very confused the meaning of 'count' in a Node.  If I had to guess, the 'inorder' function has an extra call to 'inorder' after the loop that doesn't look right, but without having the full code to run and test, its difficult to say.

Comment: Thanks, that extra inorder call was a mistake and isn't actually in the code. I've removed it from the question. Maybe I can clarify count: count is the number of keys. so if I insert 'a' into an empty tree, count of that node will be one. And 'a' (since it's the key) can have two branches (count + 1). When I then insert 'g', count of this node should go to 2 and it can now have three branches, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, I think we're in the same class.  I just finished mine, and I saw the problem in your inorder traversal, with the new one too.  In that second if:

```
if (i < order-1 && current->data[i])
cout << current->data[i];
```

it does it for the order, not for how much data is currently in the node, so it's going to spit out that little bit extra.  I changed it to `i<current->data` and now it works just fine. ^^b  Just finished up.  If it doesn't work for you, sorry. ^^;

Comment: So with i < current->data, I get a compiler error ... since i is an int and current->data is a pointer (array).  However, you pointed me in the correct direction. I changed it to i < current->count and it worked perfectly! Thanks for the help :)  (maybe edit your answer to reflect the change I made)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your for-loop is going from 0 to count (inclusive) but your Node::data array isn't defined at data[count] its only defined up to data[count-1] so the last iteration of your that loop always gets garbage which sometimes might be non-zero and not show up, but othertimes might be random characters.

You need to special case your code for when "i == order" like so

```
if (current->branch[i])
    inorder(current->branch[i]);
if (i < order-1 && current->data[i])
    cout << current->data[i];
```

Comment: If I take the +1 out of the for loop condition, it doesn't always print all the chars. in iteration 4, I get 'abf' and in iteration 19 I get 'abcdefj' for example. Most (not all) of the other iterations are similarly short, but those two are the easiest to stop at a glance.

Comment: @greggory.hz Your code for inorder is assuming that it can use 'i' to access both the branch array and the data array, so when count = 4 you'll access an invalid location in data but you'll have a valid branch location.

Comment: I see what you're saying now! Thanks for that snippet. That got rid of the errant 0s. However I still have the repeated chars problem. (updating question as well)